# Synchronizing IsSelected and SelectedItem in a ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I have some images (positions) in a WPF control. Each image correlates to an item in a `ListView` beneath that control. When the user clicks on a position, I want the corresponding `ListViewItem` to be selected (and therefore highlighted) in the `ListView`. Similarly, when the user clicks on a `ListViewItem`, I want the corresponding position to be selected.

I can accomplish one behavior or the other, but I can't seem to get both working together.

I have a `Style` that sets the `IsSelected` property to `true' when a position is selected:

```
<Style x:Key="PositionItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsCurrentPositionConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="DataContext.CurrentBackplane.CurrentCard.CurrentPosition" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In my `ListView`, I set a handler for `SelectionChanged`:

```
private void Positions_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    var listView = sender as ListView;
    if (listView == null) return;
    var currentPos = listView.SelectedItem as IGraphicPositionViewModel;
    if (currentPos == null) return;
    if (currentPos != _ViewModel.CurrentBackplane.CurrentCard.CurrentPosition)
        _ViewModel.CurrentBackplane.CurrentCard.CurrentPosition = currentPos;
}
```

**The problem is** that the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem`doesn't seem to correlate well with the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView`.

Is there some other property or event I can use to synchronize these properties?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a view model with properties `SelectedPosition` and `SelectedListItem`. Then, in the event handlers of one of these properties you should change another property:

```
    private Position _selectedPosition;
    public Position SelectedPosition
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedPosition != value)
            {
                _selectedPosition = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPosition");
                _OnSelectedPositionChanged();
            }
        }
     }

     private void _OnSelectedPositionChanged()
     {
         _selectedListItem = ... ; // find corresponding item in the list
         RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedListItem"); // update selection of the ListView
     }
```

And similar code should be used in the `SelectedListItem` event handler.